# Error when trying to load pickle files in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle

I am using Google Colab to try to load pickle files to an array. However, it doesn't find the path to my data. Currently my data is set as:

```
/content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/
```

And my drive is mounted to the path:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And I have an array of pickle files, that I am trying to load them into the array, It doesn't seem to find the correct path to load those files, I have tried using the code described below:

```
p_files = [
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_1.pkl",
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_2.pkl",
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_3.pkl",
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_4.pkl",
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_5.pkl",
        "content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_6.pkl"   
    ]

loaded_pickles = []

for p in p_files:
    with open(p, 'rb') as file:
        loaded_pickles.append(pickle.load(file))
```

I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Data/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_1.pkl'
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I am having the same problem. Answer below does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify that the pickle files are in your Drive.

E.g. `"content/drive/My Drive/My Folder/Storage/My Pickle Files/pickles_1.pkl"`

Otherwise it assumes that the files are local.

Alternatively, you could port the files over to local using `shutil` or similar, but I don't see why you would.

**Response to OP's comment:** perhaps you could try porting over the files to local using something like:

```py
import shutil
for file in p_files:
    filename = file[62:]
    shutil.copy(file, filename)
new_p_files = [f[62:] for f in p_files]
```

Then load new_p_files using your original method?

Comment: I did try like that. Unfortunately for me, it outputs the same thing, even if I manually specify the path. Is there any alternative way to load those pickle files in that same order?

Comment: Have a look at my edit; maybe that will help